# Syntax error: Non-UTF-8 code starting with '\xe1"

Tags: python, python-3.x, utf-8, plotly, plotly-dash

Technically:

[image: zero input]

[image: official "plotly" input]

I just want to use "Dash" by "plotly", "getting started" example (https://plot.ly/dash/getting-started), but I cannot. Any assumptions?

I cannot define the error more then it is in title.

(I do not want to feed you with inaccurate assumptions. Thank you for possible answer :) )

Comment: Start with not using Notepad to write code. Notepad is unable to write proper UTF-8 files. Use an actual text editor. For a start you can use IDLE that comes with your Python installation, it even has syntax highlighting and autocomplete. Also... What Windows version is this?

Comment: Your source code is being read as UTF-8 because you told Python to (with encoding comment you added at the top), but you have instead saved it in a different encoding. Use a text editor that lets you save as UTF-8, or change the encoding in the header to be correct.

Comment: Also, [please don't post code or error messages as images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error was actually because of the name of my computer.

It was named "Timemachine×2", however "×" (not "x") was not an unicode character.

So I simply renamed my computer to Timemachine2 and it started to work fine.

Error was not related to the code itself.

Answer (score 3):

Your text editor has not saved the file as UTF-8, so Python can't read the file.

You have 3 options:

- Change the first line to use the correct codec. It probably is [Windows Codepage 1252](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252), given that you are using Windows and the `é` character is encoded as 0xE1 in that codec:

  ```
  # -*- coding: cp1252 -*-
  ```
- Use a text editor that lets you specify the encoding to be used when saving, like Notepad++ or Sublime Text or Visual Studio, and make sure the file is actually saved as UTF-8.
- Use only ASCII codepoints in the file; the `u'Montréal'` value can also be specified using an `\xhh` or `\uhhhh` escape sequence for the é character:

  ```
  u'Montr\u00e9al'
  ```

Comment: Thank you for answer, but I believe, that there is greater problem.
I downloaded Notedpad++, changed encoding to UTF-8, saved and even removed that "é" from "Montréal". Now it shows: UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xd7 in position 11: invadlid continuation byte

...trust me, that I have searched through a lot of "answers"

Comment: btw... how could my editor saved it wrong, where there were no data? 0 bites

Comment: @MartinMelichar: I'm sorry, I can't help debug that; I can't see exactly how you created that file or what it contains.

Comment: @MartinMelichar: a file of 0 bytes length can't cause a `UnicodeDecodeError` either; obviously you have a file with at least 11 bytes for there to be a decoding error at position 11.

Comment: System messages are in Czech or some related language, so my guess would be [cp1250](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1250). Maybe see also https://cdn.rawgit.com/tripleee/8bit/master/encodings.html#e9

Comment: Maybe better to create a new empty file, copy/paste the code, save as... and make sure you select UTF-8 as the encoding. Python also allows you to save everything as plain ASCII, at the cost of legibility (you have to use `"\u00e9"` in place of a literal `"é"`).